# UIDatePicker leaks

Tags: ios, datepicker, memory-leaks

I appear to have a leaky UIDatePicker.  I have noted memory leaks for setting the datePickerMode to show date and time.  But, I'm only trying to display date.  I'm fairly certain this is a framework leak because when I comment out several UIDatePicker property assignments, the leaks go away.  This code leaks 1 CGColor object, and 1 UIDeviceRGBColor object:

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:[self detailViewRect]];


datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate; //leaks CGColor when setting this
datePicker.hidden = NO;
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; //leaks UIDeviceRGBColor
datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];//leaks UIDeviceRGBColor
datePicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

By commenting the lines Instruments reported as offending, I get no leaks:

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:[self detailViewRect]];

//datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate; //leaks CGColor when setting this
datePicker.hidden = NO;
//datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; //leaks UIDeviceRGBColor
//datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];//leaks UIDeviceRGBColor
datePicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Without at least date mode set, the UIDatePicker is worthless.  Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Did you check the leak on the device? Or on the simulator only? Sometimes simulator has memory leak bug that does not exist on device.

Comment: Regarding workaround, how bad is the leak?

Comment: @barley Thanks for the reminder.  No leaks on the device.  I'm not using ARC. Instruments reports 50B every time the date picker is deallocated.  I don't expect users to use this with high frequency.

Comment: Having the same issue. I have ARC enabled. Not a big deal if the users aren't going to be using the date picker that much.

Answer (score 2):

This approach worked for me:

Create the DatePicker in xib instead of the programmatic approach. Then, on the Attributes Inspector, set Mode to Date.

Comment: I presume this means you were having the problem before; and that you solved the problem by doing this.  If so, what environment were you working in?  And what did you try that caused the problem previously?

Comment: Was building for iPad iOS6. Xcode 4.5.1 with iOS6.0. Initially, I created the datePicker programatically--meaning no xib file-- then I was setting the mode this way: [_datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate]; I got memory leak when I check in Instruments. I reimplemented the date picker with an xib and, instead of setting the mode like before, I set it in the xib. When I checked it in Instruments there were no leaks.

Comment: I too can confirm that if you set these attributes in IB (instead of programmatically), the `UIDatePicker` doesn't show a leak in Instruments. However, the `UIDatePicker` will leak if you set said attributes later via code (even if the `UIDatePicker` is created in IB). This is clearly a leak in the framework code, and unfortunately, until Apple fixes it, there isn't a good workaround, other than accepting that it's going to leak... : /

Comment: The leak is still here in iOS 6.1.4. I have tried also to set the date with setDate:animated: before and after the date picker is displayed but doesn't change nothing... Anyway I'm experiencing the leak when the picker is removed from the view and not when is created.

Comment: I can also confirm this. Both CGColor and UIDeviceRGBColor leak.

Comment: Hi, does anyone know if apple would reject an app because of this?

Comment: I believe this is won't be a reason for rejection.

Comment: Apple didnt reject my app, that is setup programtically as above and to me is clearly a bug in the IOS.  This used to work well. This isnt a problem with just the datepicker either. It seems to be any view that I have popping up with a date, time, listview selection etc. Itgs really a mess for me. I cant rewrite the whole app and figure out how to put all of the different functions in an xib.  Right now I am looking at another section of the code that has a list view but there is a block overlapping the list or the list isnt wide enough. I havent a clue whats wrong as this used to work well.

Comment: I wound up basically finding the places where the initWithFrame:CGRectMake was called and changing those calls width to 300. I am still testing, but I think that fixed the problems.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the original poster in iOS 8. This solution of using an xib still causes a memory leak. Manually setting `UIDatePickerModeDate` or using the Attributes Inspector both call `-[_UIDatePickerMode _yearlessYearForMonth:]` which leaks.

Comment: It's now Oct 28, 2023, and `DatePicker`, which is essentially an `UIDatePicker` wrapper, is still leaking, fix this Apple...