# Strange Leak with UIDatePicker in iOS

Tags: ios, instruments

I had a UIDeviceRGBColor leak in my App.

It seems to be a problem with UIKIt .

Below is the problem:

[image]

The leak is located in the code mentioned in the brown color:

[image]

Did any one come across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm having the same problem ...

iOS 6.0 on Device, but mine leaks in:

```
[pickerDate setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[pickerDate setMinimumDate:minimumDate];
[pickerDate setMaximumDate:today];

[pickerDate setDate:currentDateObject animated:YES]; // here is the leak, if I remove this line there is no leak, and leaks also a UIDeviceRGBColor
```

Possible duplicate, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830278/uidatepicker-leaks)

** Sorry, this should be a comment not an answer **