# UIDatePicker leaks when changes state

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIDatePicker in a static UITableViewCell. I tried performing it programmatically and by using storyboard in accordance with answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964772/4488191.
It didn't help.

Xcode Instruments Leaks show that  calls `-[_UIDatePickerMode _yearlessYearForMonth:]` which leaks.

UIDatePicker leaks when `datePickerMode` property is `UIDatePickerModeDate`. When this property is default or `UIDatePickerModeTime`there are no memory leaks.

Is it a UIDatePicker bug?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the answer is "yes, it's a UIDatePicker bug". I am using a date picker in a popover and seeing the same sort of problem. I've created a test app that demonstrates the behaviour (https://github.com/david-ape/datepickertest/) and I've posted a related question at [UIDatePicker memory leak in IOS 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30662300/1764243) in order to try to get confirmation and find possible workarounds.