# Memory leak in Apple iOS library method -[_UIDatePickerMode _yearlessYearForMonth:]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Instruments report `NSDateComponents` object leaked in `[_UIDatePickerMode _yearlessYearForMonth:]`. Here is screenshot, and as you can see there is no my code. How could it be? Is it an apple bug or what?

[image: System libs hidden]

[image: full tree]

[image: leaks]

Comment: Could be that your app is holding onto old instances. I find that is is always a good bet to figure it is my code at fault, your milage may vary.

Comment: I use date picker only for views in my controller, and I have a weak ref to it. So, only my view keeps strong ref, and view should be deleted when my controller is deleted, is not it?

Comment: I found similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662300/uidatepicker-memory-leak-in-ios-8-3